# Dispaly JSON data in Kendo UI Grid

Tags: javascript, json, kendo-grid

Hi I have Created a html, java script. I am able to bind the json data to kendo UI dropdown list and able to display that list on Html page . When is select any data in the list I am able to retrieve the selected value . Now I am trying to replace the drop down list with kendo ui grid and want to retrieve the selected row cells value . below is the code for kendo drop down list . Help would be highly appreciated.

HTML file

```
     <table style="padding-top: 20px; padding-left: 10px; display: table;" id="selectAccountTable">        <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Existing Account Found</td>
        </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>
              <!--need to display kendo grid UI , kendo drop down  is created at this input 
                <input id="accountSelect" style="width: 350px;">
            </td>
        </tr>
```

```
     JavaScript code
      function DisplayActiveAccounts(res)
      {
        var accounts = [];
        var response = $.parseJSON(res);
        for (var idx = 0; idx < response.length; idx++)
        {
        accounts.push({ 'name': response[idx].Name, 'id':  response[idx].Id, 'code': 
           response[idx].Code,'city':response[idx].City,'state':response[idx].State,'ce':response[idx].CE});

        }

        $('#selectAccountTable').show();
        selectAccountVisible = true;
       //need to create kendo ui grid instead of kendo ui drop down list
        $('#accountSelect').kendoDropDownList({
            dataTextField: "name",
            dataValueField: "accountid",

            dataSource: accounts

        });
    }

     function _okClick()
              {
              if (closeWindow) {
            //If the account select table is visible pass back selected  account code
            //need to retrieve the selected row values in returnValues variable
            if (selectAccountVisible) {
                var dropDownSelect = $("#accountSelect").data  ("kendoDropDownList");
                var listData = dropDownSelect.dataSource;
                //Get data from selecte value in drop down
                var selectedData = listData._data.filter(function (account)          { return account.id == dropDownSelect.value() });
                var returnValues = { testID: selectedData[0].id, testCode: selectedData[0].code };

            }
            closeWindow();
            }
             }
```

Comment: ok, and what's the issue?

Comment: is it possible to replace kendo drop down ui with grid ui and display it on html page. Dropdown is displayed at the input #accountselect so how to display grid there with name ,id,city,zip coulmns. Do I need to to remove the input #accountselect on html page? I want to select any row in a grid and retrieve values in the script variable. I am able to do that with dropdown list but not sure about grid.